# Property 'price' is not available for write access

Tags: esper

I am getting following error while performing update operation:
 Property 'price' is not available for write access.

updateStatement :
        update istream FaultyStream set price = 100 where id = 7;

My Event class implements java.io.Serializable. Still unable to perform update.

Answer (score 1):

For POJO event classes, I generate getter and setter methods. The IDE does that for me. Esper calls the setter method and that be 
`public void setPrice(...) {...}`.